Django Multi-Database Setup: Error when Saving to Database
I am working on a Django project where I am using multiple databases, and I need to fetch data from a read-only MySQL database. I am using the using() method in Django to query data from this read-only database. However, when I attempt to save the queryset, I encounter the following error:
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
I have reviewed the Django documentation on multiple databases (link below), which suggests that specifying the using() method should allow for reading from and writing to different databases, but in this case, I'm only trying to read from the read-only database and save to another.
Django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/#:~:text=If%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20specify%20using%2C%20the%20save
Am I missing something here, or is there an additional configuration needed when dealing with a read-only MySQL database in Django?
